# Grids Bootstrap 5 obtienen una debajo de la otra version móvil

Tags: bootstrap-5

Tengo las siguientes grids desarrolladas en bootstrap 5.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

Cuando se accede por smartphone, se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

¿Cómo consigo que las grids estén una debajo de la otra, es decir, del mismo ancho que la card 5?

El código es así:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">  
    <div class="col col-xs-12">
      <div class="card-counter primary">        
        <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold">CARD 1</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12">
      <div class="card-counter danger">     
      <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold">CARD 2</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12">
      <div class="card-counter success">
      <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold">CARD 3</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12">
      <div class="card-counter info">
       <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold">CARD 4</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12">
      <div class="card-counter warning">
      <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold">CARD 5</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

perdón por mi español.

Answer (score 0):

Debes de usar la clase `col-12` para aplicar el tamaño más pequeño del grid de Bootstrap. Más información: [Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)

Ejemplo:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">  
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="card-counter primary">        
        <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold">CARD 1</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="card-counter danger">     
      <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold">CARD 2</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="card-counter success">
      <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold">CARD 3</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="card-counter info">
       <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold">CARD 4</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      <div class="card-counter warning">
      <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold">CARD 5</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Revilla. Cuando lo pongo de esta manera, también se aplica a computadoras portátiles / de escritorio. Me gustaría que los portátiles / computadoras de escritorio permanezcan uno al lado del otro, solo en la versión móvil es uno debajo del otro.

Comment: @JM_2021 
Para conseguir lo que describes en tu comentario, simplemente tienes que usar la clase col-md.
He actualizado el ejemplo de mi respuesta con la clase col-md.